# Why does Go use bit operation in base64 encode?

Tags: encoding, go, base64

Code 2 is base64.Encode of Go.
This code uses bit operation many times.

For example,

`val := uint(src[si+0])<<16 | uint(src[si+1])<<8 | uint(src[si+2])`

And,

`val := uint(src[si+0])>>18&0x3F]`

I don't know why these bit operations are need to encode to base64.
What is the meaning of these bit operations?

Code:

```
func (enc *Encoding) Encode(dst, src []byte) {
    if len(src) == 0 {
        return
    }

    di, si := 0, 0
    n := (len(src) / 3) * 3
    for si < n {
        // Convert 3x 8bit source bytes into 4 bytes
        val := uint(src[si+0])<<16 | uint(src[si+1])<<8 | uint(src[si+2])

        dst[di+0] = enc.encode[val>>18&0x3F]
        dst[di+1] = enc.encode[val>>12&0x3F]
        dst[di+2] = enc.encode[val>>6&0x3F]
        dst[di+3] = enc.encode[val&0x3F]

        si += 3
        di += 4
    }

    remain := len(src) - si
    if remain == 0 {
        return
    }
    // Add the remaining small block
    val := uint(src[si+0]) << 16
    if remain == 2 {
        val |= uint(src[si+1]) << 8
    }

    dst[di+0] = enc.encode[val>>18&0x3F]
    dst[di+1] = enc.encode[val>>12&0x3F]

    switch remain {
    case 2:
        dst[di+2] = enc.encode[val>>6&0x3F]
        if enc.padChar != NoPadding {
            dst[di+3] = byte(enc.padChar)
        }
    case 1:
        if enc.padChar != NoPadding {
            dst[di+2] = byte(enc.padChar)
            dst[di+3] = byte(enc.padChar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: base64 works on the bits of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a commented Javascript implementation of the same algorithm: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64#Javascript

It tells you that this loop:

- takes three ASCII chars (8-bit): `src[si+0]`, `src[si+1]` and `src[si+2]`
- merges them into one 24-bit number (that's `val := uint(src[si+0])<<16 | uint(src[si+1])<<8 | uint(src[si+2])`)
- re-separate this number into four indices (6-bit) for the base64 character list. (`val>>18&0x3F` takes the 18th to 24th bit of the previously calculated number, etc.)

You can also read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples